# Xamarin SignalR - using the same connection proxy in a different Fragment/Activity

Tags: android, xamarin, signalr

Is it possible to pass the hub connection to different fragments and activities so I can use the same connection throughout the application? 
For example the proxy connection is setup like this:

```
var chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub");
```

I want to use the client method `chatHubProxy.On<string, int, string>("UpdateChatMessage", (message, color, user)` in another fragment. Same as for invoking the server method, can I use the same proxy to invoke it in another Fragment/Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be easy, make your hub static. Or even better, handle all your SignalR stuff in a Singleton to centralize the logic in one place.

A clean way to do this, is subscribing to all your server events in that Singleton, then make that class re-dispatch your custom events. Here´s an example form a working application:

```
public event Action<string, User> OnShowMatchingInvite;
public event Action<MatchingResolutions, Conversation> OnMatchingResolution;
public event Action<string> OnPeerLeftConversation;
public event Action<ChatMessage> OnAddNewMessage;
public event Action<string, ChatMessageStatus> OnConfirmMessageDelivered;
public event Action<string> OnConfirmMessageReceived;
public event Action<string> OnConfirmMessageRead;
public event Action<UserChatStatus> OnChangeUserChatStatus;
public event Action<string> OnConversationKilled;

private void ProxySubscriber(IHubProxy hubProxy)
{
    hubProxy.On<string, User>(Settings.HubListenerShowMatchingInvite, 
            (matchingUid, peer) => OnShowMatchingInvite?.Invoke(matchingUid, peer));

    hubProxy.On<MatchingResolutions, Conversation>(Settings.HubListenerHandleMatchingResolution,
            (resolution, conversation) => OnMatchingResolution?.Invoke(resolution, conversation));

    hubProxy.On<string>(Settings.HubListenerPeerLeftConversation, 
            conversationId => OnPeerLeftConversation?.Invoke(conversationId));

    hubProxy.On<ChatMessage>(Settings.HubListenerAddNewMessage, 
            message => OnAddNewMessage?.Invoke(message));

    hubProxy.On<string, ChatMessageStatus>(Settings.HubListenerConfirmMessageDelivered, 
            (messageUid, status) => OnConfirmMessageDelivered?.Invoke(messageUid, status));

    hubProxy.On<string>(Settings.HubListenerConfirmMessageReceived, 
            uid => OnConfirmMessageReceived?.Invoke(uid));

    hubProxy.On<string>(Settings.HubListenerConfirmMessageRead, 
            uid => OnConfirmMessageRead?.Invoke(uid));

    hubProxy.On<UserChatStatus>(Settings.HubListenerChangeUserChatStatus, 
            status => OnChangeUserChatStatus?.Invoke(status));

    hubProxy.On<string>(Settings.HubListenerHandleConversationKilled,
            conversationId => OnConversationKilled?.Invoke(conversationId));
}
```

Then you can subscribe/unsubscribe to those events from your activity/fragment:

```
protected override void OnPause()
{
    base.OnPause();
    // Don´t forget to unsubscribe
    YourSingleton.Instance.OnAddNewMessage -= OnAddNewMessage;
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    base.OnResume();

    YourSingleton.Instance.OnAddNewMessage += OnAddNewMessage;
}

private void OnAddNewMessage(ChatMessage message)
{
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: Great answer! This really puts things into perspective.

Comment: Just one question. In this case, where will I instantiate the class "YourSignleton". Will it be inside the fragments/Activities where I will have the SignalR activity? In this case will I have to provide a hubProxy as an argument to the method "ProxySubscriber"?

Comment: A singleton is a well known pattern that will instantiate itself and just one time in the whole app live cycle, whenever you access to Singletonclass.Instance. Search for it and you'll find many different implementations. The idea is to handle the signalr connection and hub all together in that class because you just need a single connection/hub in your app.

Comment: okay so I will provide the hubProxy once and the handlers in different classes will be called whenever the publisher event is invoked?

Comment: nvm I think I understood your answer :) I will let you know if there's any confusion implementing my solution

Comment: You can create the hub instance in the very same class. Other classes don´t need to know the hub exists if you use that code. In my example, there is a parameter `IHubProxy` due to an specific architecture. Just ignore it :)

Comment: I never heard of singleton before hence the confusion. It all makes sense to me now.

Comment: I'm facing this issue here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37788873/signalr-connection-wouldnt-start-inside-a-singleton-class  Can you please have a look.

Comment: I've run into another issue. Can you please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38158042/app-crashes-when-trying-to-connect-to-signalr-server-after-disconnecting-it