# SignalR connection wouldn't start inside a singleton class

Tags: c#, singleton, signalr

I have setup my signalR connection inside a singleton class so I can use the same connection throughout my entire project. The problem is that the connection never starts and the code never executes beyond the line `await hubConnection.Start()` however when I do this outside the single class, then the connection is initiated in an instant. I wonder what I'm doing wrong. 
Here's my definition of the singleton class:

```
public sealed class ProxySubscriber
{
    private static volatile ProxySubscriber instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();
    private IHubProxy chatHubProxy = null;
    private HubConnection hubConnection = null;
    public event Action<string, string> OnConnect;
    private ProxySubscriber()
    {
        if (hubConnection == null) { hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://cforbeginners.com:901"); }
        if (chatHubProxy == null) { chatHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("ChatHub"); }

        chatHubProxy.On<string, string>("onConnected", (id, username) => OnConnect.Invoke(id, username));
    }

    private async Task<string> StartConnection()
    {
        await hubConnection.Start();

        return "Connection started..";
    }

    public async void InvokeConnect()
    {
        await chatHubProxy.Invoke("Connect", "Mujtaba");
    }
    public static async Task<ProxySubscriber> GetInstance()
    {
        if (instance == null)
        {
            lock (syncRoot)
            {
                if (instance == null)
                {
                    instance = new ProxySubscriber();

                }
            }
        }

        await instance.StartConnection();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

I'm using the singleton class like this:

```
ProxySubscriber proxySubscriber = ProxySubscriber.GetInstance().Result;
proxySubscriber.OnConnect += proxySubscriber_OnConnect;
proxySubscriber.InvokeConnect();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, don´t make your GetInstance() async. Use it just to create an instance with no more logic in it.

Make `StartConnection` public and call it from outside, awaiting the call:

```
await ProxySubscriber.GetInstance().StartConnection();
ProxySubscriber.GetInstance().OnConnect += proxySubscriber_OnConnect;
ProxySubscriber.GetInstance().InvokeConnect();
```

If you need to run this code from non async methods:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => {
    await ProxySubscriber.GetInstance().StartConnection();
    ProxySubscriber.GetInstance().OnConnect += proxySubscriber_OnConnect;
    ProxySubscriber.GetInstance().InvokeConnect();
});
```

More details:

1. The name of your class doesn´t look correct to me. It would be better something like `SignalRClientHelper`.
2. You don´t need to check for null values on the constructor, as it will be null with no doubt `if (hubConnection == null)`
3. Why do you have a "Connect" method on the server? When you do `await hubConnection.Start();` you are already connecting. If you just want to asign a username to a connection, you can pass that username in a header before you call Start(): `hubConnection.Headers.Add("username", "Mujtaba");`
4. If you want to make this class reliable, you need to handle SignalR disconnections (but that would be a different question)
5. Whenever you call `chatHubProxy.Invoke("whatever");` you may get an exception if the connection is lost at some point, and that will make your application crash. [Wrap it in a try/catch](https://github.com/xleon/QueuedSignalRClient/blob/master/QueuedSignalR.Client/QueuedSignalRClient.cs#L218) statement and handle the exception as you need.
6. `StartConnection` should check if there is already a connection going on. So if you call it 100 times, it would connect just once.

In general, you should learn from [SignalR connection live cycle](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) and implement some logic at the time the connection is lost.

Take a look [here](https://github.com/xleon/QueuedSignalRClient/blob/master/QueuedSignalR.Client/QueuedSignalRClient.cs#L165), [here](https://github.com/xleon/QueuedSignalRClient/blob/master/QueuedSignalR.Client/QueuedSignalRClient.cs#L194) and [here](https://github.com/xleon/QueuedSignalRClient/blob/master/QueuedSignalR.Client/QueuedSignalRClient.cs#L159)

Comment: cool. I'll make these changes and see if things work better. regarding point no.6, how do I check if there's already a connection going on?

Comment: also, do I have to call the StartConnection() method in each of my fragment where I'm using the instance?

Comment: I have made the changes as you said above and it works :) going to take some time out to read from those links for the better understanding of SignalR.